# Counting used/free ip adresses in subnets with python/pandas

Tags: python, pandas, ip-address

Lets say i have a list of subnets and their master subnets as of

```
| ip         | description                    | master subnet |
|------------|--------------------------------|---------------|
| 1.1.1.0/20 | master                         | /             |
| 1.1.1.0/22 | subnet n-1, no further subnets | 1.1.1.0/20    |
| 1.1.2.0/24 | subnet n-1, further subnets    | 1.1.1.0/20    |
| 1.1.3.0/29 | subnet n-2                     | 1.1.2.0/24    |
| 1.1.3.1/29 | subnet n-2                     | 1.1.2.0/24    |
```

I want to know the amount of used/free ips per master subnet.
I would do this by looking up the known subnets inside a master subnet and subtract the amount of ips from the total ips.

However, in my data the "depth" of subnets of a master subnet is not constant.
1.1.1.0/20 consists of two subnets, a /22 and a /24. Of the /22, all ips are seen as in use (no further subnets in the data). But inside the /24 not all ip adresses are used, but instead only those incorporated in the subsequent lines.

Expected result:

```
| ip         | description                    | master subnet | total | used | free |
|------------|--------------------------------|---------------|-------|------|------|
| 1.1.1.0/20 | master                         | /             | 4096  | 1040 | 3056 |
| 1.1.1.0/22 | subnet n-1, no further subnets | 1.1.1.0/20    | 1024  | 1024 | 0    |
| 1.1.2.0/24 | subnet n-1, further subnets    | 1.1.1.0/20    | 256   | 16   | 240  |
| 1.1.3.0/29 | subnet n-2                     | 1.1.2.0/24    | 8     | 8    | 0    |
| 1.1.3.1/29 | subnet n-2                     | 1.1.2.0/24    | 8     | 8    | 0    |
```

A regular `df.groupby('master subnet').sum()` would not consider this hierarchical structure, but instead count the /24 as fully 'used'.

Other examples in my data go to n-3 or n-4, so the problem is just reiterated on other levels.

Any clue on how to tackle this?

Answer (score 0):

You can first calculate `total` by splitting the prefix. Then `used` by grouping by `master subnet` then mapping `ip`. Fill NA values with `total`. You'll then have to remap `used` until all values are set before subtracting:

```
df['total'] = 2**(32 - df['ip'].str.split('/', expand=True)[1].astype(int))
subnet_total = df.groupby('master subnet')['total'].sum()
df['used'] = df['ip'].map(subnet_total).fillna(df['total']).astype(int)

while True:
    old_used_col = df['used'].copy()
    subnet_used = df.groupby('master subnet')['used'].sum()
    df.loc[df['ip'].isin(subnet_used.index),'used'] = df['ip'].map(subnet_used)
    if all(df['used'] == old_used_col):
        break

df['free'] = df['total'] - df['used']
print(df)
```

Output:

```
           ip                     description master subnet  total  used  free
0  1.1.1.0/20                          master             /   4096  1040  3056
1  1.1.1.0/22  subnet n-1, no further subnets    1.1.1.0/20   1024  1024     0
2  1.1.2.0/24     subnet n-1, further subnets    1.1.1.0/20    256    16   240
3  1.1.3.0/29                      subnet n-2    1.1.2.0/24      8     8     0
4  1.1.3.1/29                      subnet n-2    1.1.2.0/24      8     8     0
```

Edit: adding a while loop to handle any depth